# rails new command creating this files only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

[image: My Terminal ubuntu]

Hello Everyone , I am new to Rails . Creating a new Rail project with new command it is just creating these files rather creating the whole project.

Comment: What does `which rails` and `rails -v` return in your command line?

Comment: rails - v  = Rails 5.2.4
which rails = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/rails

Comment: And does a `ls` in the project folder confirm there are no more files than those in the image? Try reinstalling the rails gem.

Comment: i will try. thank you.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have git installed. You need to install git first `sudo apt-get install git`